# Are there any "Problems and Solutions" books or notes for advanced Quantum Field theory or/and String theory or/and Supersymmetry?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, resource-recommendations, supersymmetry, education

I was wondering whether or not there are any good resources of the type "Problems and Solutions" on String theory, on Supersymmetry and on advanced Quantum Field theory (separately).

[I am aware that there is a problems and solutions book on introductory Quantum Field theory by Radovanovic called "Problem book in Quantum Field theory" but it mostly covers material found in a first graduate-level Quantum field theory course.]

Comment: Why do you need problem and solution sets at such an advanced level? The best resources for problems at this level are well-written research papers.

Comment: Becker, Becker, and Schwarz "String Theory and M-Theory" has many problems with solutions throughout the text.

Comment: @pathintegral extra practice! I also very much like very creative problems

Comment: @bapowell Thanks for the suggestion! You are absolutely right! Although most of its problems (at least in the first chapter I've read) have to do with basic derivations that they leave as exercises

Comment: There are problem sets from the IAS QFT/strings workshop written by Witten and D'Hoker: https://www.math.ias.edu/qft

Answer (score 2):

I only know of one for quantum field theory at all: [Problem Book in Quantum Field Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540770135) by Voja Radovanovic, and it's introductory QFT level.

Comment: Yeah, I've solved some problems from there, but it seems to be introductory level, as you point out.. I want more advanced stuff.. (I also mention it in my question :) )

Comment: [Atkinson and Johnson 2004](https://www.amazon.com/Exercises-Quantum-Field-Theory-Self-Contained/dp/1589490312).

Answer (score 2):

A recent book by [François Gelis](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/quantum-field-theory/5484B936BB6323A0991E334AE9A02A49) is in my opinion a fantastic book on QFT.
The first half of the book is all the basics up to and including non-abelian gauge theory. While the second half introduces unrelated modern concepts in each chapter. For example it has a very nice review on the spinor helicity formalism, etc
Lots of exercises and solutions at the end.
I highly recommend.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There are no solutions of the exericse in this book (although there are a handful of examples per chapter)

Comment: Ah i see. On his website he says that the solution manual is upon request. Very sneaky. Well i can send you the solution privately if you want (i studied under him)

Comment: That would actually be very helpful, if you don't mind. Shall we move this to a private chat?

Comment: Sure thing. How do I do this? (new to the site, I don't seem to be able to pm you)

Comment: I have never done that either. Maybe try this link:
https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/110361/on-gelis-book?tab=general

Answer (score 1):

You can try the problem's on [Peter van Nieuwenhuizen's](https://sites.google.com/site/vannieuwenhuizenfieldtheory/home) website. Try the homework and exam problems from each iteration of the course.

Answer (score 1):

[A solution manual for Polchinski's "String Theory"](https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.4408) Is a truly wonderful solver for Polchinski's textbooks.

Probably the most difficult task when starting to study perturbative string theory is to reach the point at which you are comfortable with the formalism of two dimensional CFTs. For that [A Collection of Exercises in Two-Dimensional Physics, Part 1](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0003190) is a rather impressive source of useful tricks that can be used to mastering world-sheet techniques.